# How to access UIAPane items in UIAutomation

Tags: powershell, ui-automation, microsoft-ui-automation

I recently started using UIAutomation framework for Powershell from MSDN, and i noticed that Get-Uiapane commandlet giving timeout error, 
i am running this command for UI Testing for audio page in dell systems. by inspector tool i get Hierarchy of the elements in the  window shown the hierarchy below. 
is there any idea wny get-UIapane is not working?  any thoughts..

- I can see Get-UIAwindow command let working with supported windows.

Command i tried

> Get-UiaPane -Class '#32770' -Name 'Dell Audio'

Inspect Element output for this window.
[image]